# How to declare a var inside a class inside in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to declare the following things:

```
            var simlBot = new SimlBot();

            var botUser = simlBot.CreateUser();

            var packageString = File.ReadAllText("SIMLPackage.simlpk");
            simlBot.PackageManager.LoadFromString(packageString);
```

If I declare it directly in the class I get: "The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code"

I can't declare it inside an if statement because I can't access it from outside.

```
        if (hasBotBeenCreated == false)
        {
            var simlBot = new SimlBot();

            var botUser = simlBot.CreateUser();

            var packageString = File.ReadAllText("SIMLPackage.simlpk");
            simlBot.PackageManager.LoadFromString(packageString);
        }
```

I need to use the following form inside a function:

```
        var chatRequest = new ChatRequest(textReceived, botUser);
        var chatResult = simlBot.Chat(chatRequest);
```

What can I do? The problem is that the last snippet of code can't access botUser and simlBot. The way I have it working now is recreating the object every time the function is called, but that takes a lot of time.

My complete code is

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string textEntered = "";

    string response = "";

    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    bool hasBotBeenCreated = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textEntered = textBox1.Text;

        textBox1.Text = "";

        if (textEntered != "")
        {
            sendToAI(textEntered);
        }
    }

    void sendToAI(string textReceived)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textEntered);

        response = getResponse(textEntered);

        listBox1.Items.Add(response);
        synth.Speak(response);
    }

    string getResponse(string textReceived)
    {
        if (hasBotBeenCreated == false)
        {
            var simlBot = new SimlBot();

            var botUser = simlBot.CreateUser();

            var packageString = File.ReadAllText("SIMLPackage.simlpk");
            simlBot.PackageManager.LoadFromString(packageString);
        }

        var chatRequest = new ChatRequest(textReceived, botUser);//These two can't access the objects created above
        var chatResult = simlBot.Chat(chatRequest);

        if (chatResult.Success)
        {
            var botMessage = chatResult.BotMessage;
            return botMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            return "I don't have a response for that";
        }
    }
}
```

Revision 2:

```
    string getResponse(string textReceived)
    {
        SimlBot simlBot;

        BotUser botUser;

        if (hasBotBeenCreated == false)
        {
            simlBot = new SimlBot();

            botUser = simlBot.CreateUser();

            var packageString = File.ReadAllText("SIMLPackage.simlpk");
            simlBot.PackageManager.LoadFromString(packageString);
        }

        var chatRequest = new ChatRequest(textReceived, botUser); //These get the error
        var chatResult = simlBot.Chat(chatRequest);
        if (chatResult.Success)
        {
            var botMessage = chatResult.BotMessage;
            return botMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            return "I don't have a response for that";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't declare it as `var` instead declare it as `ChatRequest chatRequest`

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. My problem was that I can't access botUser and simlBot from inside the function.

Comment: you need to show the ***entire*** definition.  showing a snippet of code that could be anywhere, and then a snippet that could be anywhere else (even in a different file) and then asking why one can't access the other doesn't give us much to go on.  read about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: There are a ton of approaches but these depend on what you're trying to achieve. Don't look at it from a point of I need to access this from there. Instead model your code to reflect what you're trying to achieve. Without more context it's difficult to give you advice. Simplest is to add `simlBot` and `botUser` as members of the class.

Comment: I added the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the members:

```
 SimlBot simlBot;
 WhatEverTypeOfCreateUserIs botUser;
```

Then initialize them:

```
    if (hasBotBeenCreated == false)
    {
        simlBot = new SimlBot();

        botUser = simlBot.CreateUser();

       ....
    }
```

---------- Full Code ----------

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string textEntered = "";

    string response = "";

    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    bool hasBotBeenCreated = false;

    SimlBot simlBot;

    BotUser botUser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textEntered = textBox1.Text;

        textBox1.Text = "";

        if (textEntered != "")
        {
            sendToAI(textEntered);
        }
    }

    void sendToAI(string textReceived)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textEntered);

        response = getResponse(textEntered);

        listBox1.Items.Add(response);
        synth.Speak(response);
    }

    string getResponse(string textReceived)
    {
        if (hasBotBeenCreated == false)
        {
            simlBot = new SimlBot();

            botUser = simlBot.CreateUser();

            var packageString = File.ReadAllText("SIMLPackage.simlpk");
            simlBot.PackageManager.LoadFromString(packageString);
        }

        var chatRequest = new ChatRequest(textReceived, botUser);//These two can't access the objects created above
        var chatResult = simlBot.Chat(chatRequest);

        if (chatResult.Success)
        {
            var botMessage = chatResult.BotMessage;
            return botMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            return "I don't have a response for that";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it, and the declaring worked fine, but when I try to use it, it says: "Use of unassigned local variable 'botUser'" and "Use of unassigned local variable 'simlBot'"

Comment: They aren't local variables. Declare them straight after `bool hasBotBeenCreated = false;` Make sure you also remove the `var` from `var SimlBot` and `botUser` within your function.

Comment: I've added the full code. You had declared these as local variables. If you want them to last longer than the life of the function then they need to be declared within the class.